# Weird Foreign Characters with PHP mail function

Tags: php, html

I have searched for this all over the web but can't seem to find an answer.  I understand that mail() is not the best, but I would like to use it for its ease.

I am sending a basic html email using mail() and file_get_contents, but the sent emails have what looks to be Chinese characters in the message summary when viewed in Apple Mail.  Unfortunately as a new user I can't post images.

I am sending the message to a gmail account that is viewed in Apple Mail, so the summary appears underneath the subject line.  When I actually view the email, the Chinese characters aren't there.  I really want to get rid of these weird characters and would appreciate your help!  Thank you!

Comment: Do the characters look like diamonds with question marks in them? This sounds like a character encoding issue.

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to send the mail and the mail content before and after it gets sent?

Comment: In short: you need to ensure that the encoding of the body is good, declare that encoding using a header and make sure all header lines are ASCII only and MIME encoded when necessary. Without more details it's hard to answer what in particular you're doing wrong.

Comment: The content of the actual message is fine.  Just a weird quirk with apple mail, because when I read the message directly from gmail the email is fine.  But in apple mail, the _summary_ has a couple Chinese characters.  Not a big deal.  Just bothers me.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to get Chinese characters without wanting to is to have some English text in a common 8-bit encoding (Ascii, ISO-8859-1, windows-1252, whatever) and have it misinterpreted as if it were UTF-16 encoded. This way, you would turn e.g. “ab”, which is U+0061 U+0062, to U+6162 or U+6261 (depending on endianness), i.e. to 慢 or 扡.

Thus, the issue is most probably with character encodings. Without further information, it is not possible to say what really happens. To analyze the situation, it is probably best to test first without involving gmail, which may well be the culprit here.

Comment: So strange.  I initially tried changing the encoding but it didn't work.  Sorry I didn't paste my code.  This is my first post on stackoverflow.

Comment: Just a problem in the summary of apple mail.  Must be a weird encoding quirk with apple mail summary.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that mail() is not the best

This is a very revealing comment.

There's always multiple ways to solve a problem which is anything more than trivial, and the different appraches have different advantages / risks / issues. For most purposes, mail() is an ideal way to to send an email from a PHP application.

However sending HTML email over SMTP is far from trivial. You need a detailled understanding of mime and character encoding. Explaining these goes well beyond the scope of a SO answer.

Either go spend a couple of weeks reading up on the subject and carrying out experiments using various user agents (Microsoft can't even get this right - semi colon seperator, crappy smiley handling) or use a tool such as [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: Thanks.  I know what you mean.  I should have said that it is not optimal for all situations.  I just wrote that so people wouldn't simply tell me to use swiftmailer and phpmailer.